# userAgent jQuery script conflicting

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, css, jquery-mobile

I have some jQuery that sets the height and width of various divs.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
$('.slide') .css({'height': h});
$('.slide') .css({'width': w});
});
```

This has worked fine until recently i added a script to load userAgent specific css files, one for iPad, Android, and everything else. For some reason the two scripts wont run together. I can have EITHER the correct sized div, OR a multi platform website.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
document.write("<link type=\"text\/css\" *etc*>");}

else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)){
document.write("<link type=\"text\/css\" *etc*>");}

else {
document.write("<link type=\"text\/css\" *etc*>");
}
```

Any reason this last bit of script is stopping the first one from running?

Comment: from where do you call the code to load the stylesheet?

Comment: my head tag in order is,
- all links for fonts etc
- userAgent script
- all other js scripts
- div height script

Comment: I mean where do you call the second code fragment?

Comment: im sorry i dont fully understand, does this help?
http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/Boutinot/index.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be the following.

The `jQuery.ready()` function is called as soon as the dom structure is fully loaded, but before any external stylesheets are loaded. This means that there is a potential race condition between the code loading and applying the stylesheet and the code modifying the css.

You might try to call this fragment in the `jQuery.onload()`.

```
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();
$('.slide') .css({'height': h});
$('.slide') .css({'width': w});
```